# Django dynamic OR queries

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `MultipleChoiceField` on a form holding car makes. I want to filter my database of cars to the makes that were checked but this causes a problem. How do I get all the `Q(make=...)` statements in dynamically?

How I start: `['value1', 'value2', ...]`

How I want to end: `Q(col='value1') | Q(col='value2') | ...`

I've couple of other methods. I've tried appending querysets for each make and doing it the other way around (doing multiple excludes) but they were both really slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried: `Model.objects.filter(make__in=list_of_makes)` ?

The list_of_makes is what is returned by the `MultipleChoiceField`

See [the query set reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) about the `__in` operator.

Answer (score 4):

There was another method provided in #django:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x | y, [Q1, Q2, Q3, ...])
```

[Ber's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352178/django-dynamic-or-queries#352208) is great for this instance but if you need to filter on dynamic columns, mapping looks like the next cleanest way.

Comment: You can use the __in operator here also, if you dynamically construct the arguments: 

    query={'%s__in'%col_name: list_of_values}
    Model.objects.filter(**query)

using keyword arg expansion

Comment: I think, that map in that case should be replaced by reduce.

Answer (score 3):

I tried Oli's answer but it didn't work, even with reduce() since it appears Q objects do not accept dictionaries as argument:

Here's how I had it working:

```
# These are the fields I want to search with an OR clause
search_fields = ['title__icontains', 'publisher__name__icontains', 'authors__name__icontains']

search = 'search string'
clauses = []
for item in search_fields:
    clauses.append(queryset.filter(**{item: search}))
    queryset  = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, clauses).distinct()
```

Check for performance issues since I was only able to test with a small dataset.