# django queryset from a list or set

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am having list (could be a set or another iterable) of, say, emails strings, and I want to get all of a models' objects that have attribute 'email' matching any of those emails.

I am doing:

```
from myapp.models import MyModel
l=['email1@x.com', 'email2@x.com', 'email3@y.com']
from django.db.models import Q

q = Q(email=l[0])
for e in l[1:]:
    q |= Q(email=e)
MyModel.objects.get(q)
```

Is there a way to do it more elegantly?

Comment: See also the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/352208/11527

Comment: @Ber Yep didn't find it when searched in previous questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(email__in=l)
```